# Python - Web Scraping using Login

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data on the below website -

https://www.<>.org.in/

On the top right, there is Login -> Client Login, then there is a prompt to enter credentials.

Can anyone please help? I tried using network tab of firefox, but i am not able to make any headway.

Comment: Did you try that in Selenium and something did not work for you ?

Comment: I'm unable to identify the exact element to try in selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a ruuning instance of driver, the below should work for you :

```
driver.get("https://www.<>.org.in/#/home")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[placement='bottom-left']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Client Login"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username"))).send_keys(" your username")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys(" your password")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']/../following-sibling::div[1]/button"))).click()
```